# Bash - cat in a hidden . file or write to it

Tags: linux, bash, cat

Let's say I make a file .history.txt:

```
touch .history.txt
```

and I try to write to it:

```
cat > .history.txt
```

after having done that all I get is:

```
bash: .history.txt: is a directory
```

What I need is to be able to write some text to it like I would be able to any normal file. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You used `mkdir .history.txt` at some point (or something else did) and you have a directory there instead of a file. What does `ls -ld .history.txt{,/*}` say?

Comment: Something else must have done it, I guess, but how can I actually make a file?

Comment: A file doesn't need to exist to write to it. `cat > .history.txt` should work on its own. You either need to remove the existing directory `rm -rf .history.txt` or use a different file name.

Comment: The methods you list will make a file. Use `ls -a` to show files and directories that already exist, and either delete some or pick an unused name. The "dot means hidden" convention is irrelevant.

Comment: `touch` would have created an empty file if a directory had not already existed there. That being said so would that `cat` command as would have `: > .history.txt`. The shell creates the output file whether or not the command writes anything or even runs correctly (i.e. `no-such-command > .history.txt` will create the file too).

Comment: Because as far as I know `touch file` should make a file unlike mkdir

Comment: A file absolutely needs to exist (for some definition of "exist") to write to it. The shell creates the file for you with `cat > .history.txt`.

Comment: `touch` does create files but that's a side-effect in a sense. `touch` updates timestamps on whatever arguments it gets (file or directory).

Comment: How to view content of a hidden file? I tried "cat .hidden" becomes "cat: .hidden: No such device or address" :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A file doesn't need to already exist in order to redirect output to it (the shell will create the file if necessary). But Bash is telling you that `.history.txt` already exists and is a directory, so you can't write to it.

You either need to remove the existing directory `rm -rf .history.txt` or use a different file name. Then `cat > .whatever.txt` should work on its own.

Comment: It seems like a bad idea to me to delete a directory forced without inspecting its content. A `find history.txt` surely doesn't hurt.

Comment: I hypothesize that files named `*.txt` that are directories are always an accident.

Comment: Thank you, it had no important content in it I created it by accident.